# Hierarchical query for graph from subquery factoring to Oracles ``connect by``

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I have a simple directed graph structure as tables in the form of:

```
CREATE TABLE node (id NUMBER(8, 0), NAME VARCHAR2(100));
CREATE TABLE edge (parent NUMBER(8, 0), child NUMBER(8, 0));
```

where `node` stores all nodes and `edge` all directed edges from `parent` to `child`.
What I now want is a view that displays all paths from all roots (nodes without incoming edges) to all other nodes within the graph (including zero length paths). The graph is guaranteed to have no cycles.

I used a hierarchical query using subquery factoring and ended up with this:

```
WITH rec_view(id, parent, lvl, root_id, path) AS (
    SELECT
        id
        , NULL
        , 1 lvl
        , id root_id
        , '/' || TO_CHAR(id) path
    FROM node g
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM edge h WHERE h.child = g.id)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        hier.child
        , prev.id
        , prev.lvl + 1 lvl
        , prev.root_id
        , prev.path || '/' || hier.child path
    FROM rec_view prev
        JOIN edge hier ON prev.id = hier.parent 
)
SELECT
    n.id, n.NAME, v.root_id, v.lvl, v.path
FROM
    rec_view v
    JOIN node n ON v.id = n.id
```

With this test data, I get the expected result of 10 rows.

```
INSERT INTO node VALUES (1, 'KBR');
INSERT INTO node VALUES (2, 'H');
INSERT INTO node VALUES (3, 'N');
INSERT INTO node VALUES (4, 'KBR H');
INSERT INTO node VALUES (5, 'KBR N');
INSERT INTO node VALUES (6, 'Dummy');
INSERT INTO node VALUES (7, 'Nach H');

INSERT INTO edge VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO edge VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO edge VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO edge VALUES (3, 5);
INSERT INTO edge VALUES (4, 7);

ID  Name   Root  Level    Path
------------------------------
1   KBR       1      1      /1
2   H         2      1      /2
3   N         3      1      /3
4   KBR H     1      2    /1/4
4   KBR H     2      2    /2/4
5   KBR N     1      2    /1/5
5   KBR N     3      2    /3/5
6   Dummy     6      1      /6
7   Nach H    2      3  /2/4/7
7   Nach H    1      3  /1/4/7
```

However, what I'd like to have is a query that uses Oracles `CONNECT BY` feature, as I think it's easier to read and understand than the subquery factoring one and it's also the preferred way for hierarchical queries in our company. But the queries I come up with, lead me with too many results. What I got was this:

```
SELECT
    parent.id id
    , parent.NAME NAME
    , connect_by_root parent.NAME root_id
    , LEVEL lvl
    , sys_connect_by_path(parent.id, '/') path
FROM
    node parent
    LEFT JOIN edge hier ON parent.id = hier.parent
START WITH
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM edge h WHERE h.child = parent.id)
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR hier.child = parent.id
```

Here I get 11 rows, instead of 10 where the row with path `/1` is included twice.

```
ID  Name    Root  Level    Path
-------------------------------
1   KBR        1      1      /1
4   KBR H      1      2    /1/4
7   Nach H     1      3  /1/4/7
1   KBR        1      1      /1
5   KBR N      1      2    /1/5
2   H          2      1      /2
4   KBR H      2      2    /2/4
7   Nach H     2      3  /2/4/7
3   N          3      1      /3
5   KBR N      3      2    /3/5
6   Dummy      6      1      /6
```

What is the problem with my query and how can I fix this to only include the required rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left join query is not returning the result as expected:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM
  3      node parent
  4      LEFT JOIN edge hier ON parent.id = hier.parent  ;
       ID NAME                                                                                PARENT     CHILD
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------- ---------
        1 KBR                                                                                      1         4
        1 KBR                                                                                      1         5
        2 H                                                                                        2         4
        3 N                                                                                        3         5
        4 KBR H                                                                                    4         7
        6 Dummy                                                                                      
        7 Nach H                                                                                     
        5 KBR N                                                                                      
8 rows selected
```

Parent.id should be joined on heir.child to bring the result in proper shape which can be used with connect by clause

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM
  3      node parent
  4      LEFT JOIN edge hier ON parent.id = hier.child  ;
       ID NAME                                                                                PARENT     CHILD
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------- ---------
        4 KBR H                                                                                    1         4
        5 KBR N                                                                                    1         5
        4 KBR H                                                                                    2         4
        5 KBR N                                                                                    3         5
        7 Nach H                                                                                   4         7
        6 Dummy                                                                                      
        1 KBR                                                                                        
        2 H                                                                                          
        3 N                                                                                          
9 rows selected
```

Now, the start with can be done with parent as null and connect the heir.parent to prior of parent.id to get the correct hierarchy

```
SQL> column name format a20
SQL> column root_id format a10
SQL> column path format a10
SQL> 
SQL> SELECT
  2      parent.id id
  3      , parent.NAME NAME
  4      , connect_by_root parent.NAME root_id
  5      , LEVEL lvl
  6      , sys_connect_by_path(parent.id, '/') path
  7  FROM
  8      node parent
  9      LEFT JOIN edge hier ON parent.id = hier.child
 10  START WITH
 11      PARENT IS NULL
 12  CONNECT BY
 13      hier.parent = PRIOR parent.id;
       ID NAME                 ROOT_ID           LVL PATH
--------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        1 KBR                  KBR                 1 /1
        4 KBR H                KBR                 2 /1/4
        7 Nach H               KBR                 3 /1/4/7
        5 KBR N                KBR                 2 /1/5
        2 H                    H                   1 /2
        4 KBR H                H                   2 /2/4
        7 Nach H               H                   3 /2/4/7
        3 N                    N                   1 /3
        5 KBR N                N                   2 /3/5
        6 Dummy                Dummy               1 /6
10 rows selected

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the problem with my query and how can I fix this to only include the required rows?

There is nothing wrong with your query. The hierarchical query is considering edges so if you include the `child` column you will see the difference in the rows with `id = 1`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/258c5a/2)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT parent.id id
     , parent.NAME NAME
     , connect_by_root parent.NAME root_id
     , LEVEL lvl
     , sys_connect_by_path(parent.id, '/') path
     , child
FROM   node parent
       LEFT JOIN edge hier
       ON parent.id = hier.parent
START WITH
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM edge h WHERE h.child = parent.id)
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR hier.child = parent.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/258c5a/2/0)**:

```
| ID |   NAME | ROOT_ID | LVL |   PATH |  CHILD |
|----|--------|---------|-----|--------|--------|
|  1 |    KBR |     KBR |   1 |     /1 |      4 |
...
|  1 |    KBR |     KBR |   1 |     /1 |      5 |
...
```

The rows are different as they have different child edges.

If you want to just get distinct rows then add the `DISTINCT` keyword.

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       parent.id id
     , parent.NAME NAME
     , connect_by_root parent.NAME root_id
     , LEVEL lvl
     , sys_connect_by_path(parent.id, '/') path
FROM   node parent
       LEFT JOIN edge hier
       ON parent.id = hier.parent
START WITH
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM edge h WHERE h.child = parent.id)
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR hier.child = parent.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/258c5a/2/1)**:

```
| ID |   NAME | ROOT_ID | LVL |   PATH |
|----|--------|---------|-----|--------|
|  2 |      H |       H |   1 |     /2 |
|  7 | Nach H |       H |   3 | /2/4/7 |
|  4 |  KBR H |       H |   2 |   /2/4 |
|  4 |  KBR H |     KBR |   2 |   /1/4 |
|  7 | Nach H |     KBR |   3 | /1/4/7 |
|  5 |  KBR N |     KBR |   2 |   /1/5 |
|  1 |    KBR |     KBR |   1 |     /1 |
|  3 |      N |       N |   1 |     /3 |
|  5 |  KBR N |       N |   2 |   /3/5 |
|  6 |  Dummy |   Dummy |   1 |     /6 |
```